# Anthos Config Management is not rendering new commits after failed one

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

I have configured Anthos Config Management in my GKE cluster, and few days ago, I did a commit that fails the reconciler, so I try to fix it doing another commit, but I get stuck in that old commit and I does not rendereing the new one. Here is the root-sync config:

```
apiVersion: configsync.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: RootSync
metadata:
  annotations:
    configmanagement.gke.io/managed-by-hub: "true"
    configmanagement.gke.io/update-time: "1640271116"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-29T08:24:01Z"
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
  generation: 2
  name: root-sync
  namespace: config-management-system
  resourceVersion: "166857826"
  uid: ...
spec:
  git:
    auth: token
    branch: develop
    dir: [FOLDER]
    period: 15s
    repo: [REPO]
    revision: HEAD
    secretRef:
      name: git-creds
  override: {}
  sourceFormat: unstructured
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-06-20T10:07:07Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-06-20T10:07:07Z"
    message: 'Available: 0/1'
    reason: Deployment
    status: "True"
    type: Reconciling
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-03-22T08:09:21Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-03-22T08:09:21Z"
    status: "False"
    type: Stalled
  observedGeneration: 2
  reconciler: root-reconciler
  rendering:
    commit: [NEWCOMMIT]
    gitStatus:
      branch: develop
      dir: [FOLDER]
      repo: [REPO]
      revision: HEAD
    lastUpdate: "2022-06-20T10:06:58Z"
    message: Rendering skipped
  source:
    commit: [OLDCOMMIT]
    gitStatus:
      branch: develop
      dir: [FOLDER]
      repo: [REPO]
      revision: HEAD
    lastUpdate: "2022-06-19T16:21:46Z"
  sync:
    commit: [OLDCOMMIT]
    errors:
    - code: "2009"
      errorMessage: |-
        KNV2009: Operation cannot be fulfilled on resourcegroups.kpt.dev "root-sync": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

        For more information, see https://g.co/cloud/acm-errors#knv2009
    gitStatus:
      branch: develop
      dir: [FOLDER]
      repo: [REPO]
      revision: HEAD
    lastUpdate: "2022-06-19T16:21:46Z"
```

Does anyone know how to force to skip that fail reconciliation? Or have I to reset all ACM configuration in the cluster?

Comment: can you share the screenshot of what is  the exact error you are getting

Comment: That’s the problem. It does not appears in the root-reconcilier any error message and it does not tries to skip that

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/how-to/troubleshooting-config-sync  I hope this link is helpful to you